# unable to use merge attribute with list tag in spring

Tags: spring, list, merge

```
<bean id="parentTriangle" class="org.kiran.spring.Triangle" abstract="true">
<property name="type">
<list>
    <value>equilateral</value>
    <value>scalene</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="triangle" class="org.kiran.spring.Triangle" parent="parentTriangle" >
<property name="type">
    <list merge="true">
        <value>isosceles</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Its throwing an error
Do i need to add anything to the header to make it work??

Comment: What error does it throw exactly?

Comment: please add context, that is code for your classes and the exception. Good point Xaerxess , +1

Comment: all the reqd imports r made.. it throws an  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException

Comment: Its throwing an  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException

public class Triangle{
    private List<String> type;
    public List<String> getType() {
 return type;
    }
    public void setType(List<String> type) {
  this.type = type;
    }
    public void draw(){
    for(String i:type){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}

Comment: public class DrawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle=(Triangle) ctx.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
    ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}

Comment: Edit your question with the appropriate context so that we may better help you with your issue.  Do not provide said context through comments, as it should be obvious by now that it is not easy to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spring config is just fine, you are missing a scheme configuration.
Verify that your spring config have the following header :

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
     ">`